# DB2 SQL HOW TO RETURN 1 ROW ON JOIN TABLE FROM INNER JOIN TABLE

Tags: sql, join, db2, distinct

```
SELECT GARAGE, MAKE
FROM NEIGHBORHOOD_TABLE A
JOIN VEHICLES_TABLE B ON B.MAKE = A.MAKE DISTINCT BY B.MAKE
WHERE A.ZIPCODE = MY_ZIP_CODE
;
```

Now I want to return all the garages in my zip code with a FORD make. Now the Vehicles-Table can have multiple Models of FORD Makes on the join but I only want to return 1 row for FORD make not all the models FUSION, RANGER, F150....probably a bad example but the Idea is I want to return multiple rows from Table A that Match Table B however Table B may have multiple rows that match table A but I want only 1 row, sort of distinct by B.MAKE.

This is a DB2 SQL database.
Thanks if you can figure out what I am asking.

Comment: please provide the actual data set examples

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`. For example

```
select *
from (
  select
    a.garage,
    a.make,
    row_number() over(partition by a.make order by b.id) as rn
  from neighborhood_table a
  join vehicles_table b on b.make = a.make
  where a.zipcode = 12345
) x
where rn = 1
```

Note that you need to add an ordering criteria to decide which row to pick when there are multiple ones per make; I added `order by b.id` but you should change according to your criteria.

Alternatively, you can use a lateral query to get a single row per group.

Comment: @NathanHughes `ROW_NUMBER()` works perfectly well in DB2. See running example at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=23f3d79a612859b1a5dfbf8887dcca0d

Comment: Nice I didn’t know, thought it was specific to MS SQL and oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.GARAGE, A.MAKE
FROM NEIGHBORHOOD_TABLE A
JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT MAKE
FROM VEHICLES_TABLE
) B ON B.MAKE = A.MAKE
WHERE A.ZIPCODE = MY_ZIP_CODE
```